# Swift: Make vertical scrolling feed with programmatically sized UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm building a scrolling feed in my app with data grabbed from a database (firebase).  I'm not very experienced in Swift as most of the stuff I do is web design.  What I'm looking for is a good way to size the height of my UIViews.  Here is what I currently have (fixed height): [image]

Here's my code UIView class:

```
class eventView: UIView {

    let eventDate : UILabel = {
        let eventDate = UILabel()
        eventDate.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        eventDate.numberOfLines = 0
        eventDate.textAlignment = .center
        return eventDate
    }()
    let eventTitle : UILabel = {
    Same thing as eventDate
    }()
    let eventDesc : UILabel = {
    same thing as eventDate
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.addSubview(eventDate)
        eventDate.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        eventDate.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.addSubview(eventTitle)
        eventTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        eventTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        eventTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: eventDate.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        self.addSubview(eventDesc)
        eventDesc.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        eventDesc.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        eventDesc.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: eventTitle.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is my for list that displays these UIViews:

```
    var i = 0
    for data in self.eventViewData {
        let view = eventView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: ( CGFloat(170 * i)), width: self.scrollView.frame.width - 20, height: CGFloat(150)))
        view.center.x = self.scrollView.center.x
        view.eventDate.text = data.date
        view.eventTitle.text = data.title
        view.eventDesc.text = data.description
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)

        i += 1
    }
```

I usually am using HTML div's and such so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to style these.  Any information or links to tutorials on how to programmatically adjust constraints to the UILabels in my eventViews are also appreciated.

Comment: just use self size tableview cell

Comment: I agree. Self sizing table view cells are the default! Why fool around trying to roll your own when iOS just hands you this functionality for free?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation to use table view.  I didn't know much about it as I'm new to swift but it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to calculate the desired height seems to be the question. While there are a lot of ways to do this one approach would be something like this:

```
    func heightForView(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        label.font = font
        label.text = text
        label.sizeToFit()
        return label.frame.height
}

    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20.0)
    var height = heightForView("This is just a load of text", font: font, width: 100.0)
    // apply height to desired view
```

I prefer to put the heightForView function in an extension myself but it isn't required.

Comment: Thanks, this worked pretty well but I did end up switching to a table view as I learned more about the subject.  Thanks for sharing this though, I'll be sure to use it next time I need to calculate the height of a label!

Comment: Glad to hear it, a tableView seems like the right way to go in my opinion also. Thanks for check mark and Good luck with the project!

Comment: Good morning Daniel. Please do not roll back my edits. My view is they would be upheld by a moderator, but I'd rather not go down that route. Please open a chat window with me if you want to understand editing and curation here - I am happy to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you're using table view, why not do dynamic height? Good reference https://www.raywenderlich.com/1067-self-sizing-table-view-cells

In essense, you use auto layout to define your top and bottom constraint accordingly for every element in your cell, and your table view delegation/data source method for heightforrow and estimatedheightforrow, return UITableViewAutomaticDimension